# can't install node epoll

Tags: raspbian, node.js

I'm trying to install [epoll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/epoll) on my pi(RPi 1 model B 700Mz 256MB). And only because it's a dependency of onff. It's related to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28139/cant-install-npm-onoff-on-raspberrypi).
My node version is:v0.12.0

I'm running this command:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm epoll
```

and getting back this error:

```
> epoll@0.1.13 install /home/pi/node_modules/epoll
> node-gyp rebuild

child_process: customFds option is deprecated, use stdio instead.
gyp: /root/.node-gyp/0.12.0/common.gypi not found (cwd: /home/pi/node_modules/epoll) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.12.26-rpi-aufs
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/node_modules/epoll
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Linux 3.12.26-rpi-aufs
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "epoll"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! epoll@0.1.13 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the epoll@0.1.13 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the epoll package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls epoll
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
```

Any idea why?
Note: All this works fine in my RPi2 model B.

Comment: It turns out that the issue was related to berryboot. After reinstalling raspbian without berryboot it all worked fine.
For more info have a look at [this ticket][1]



  [1]: https://github.com/fivdi/epoll/issues/14